# epoll instantly returns on stdin

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I tried to do nonblocking IO with stdin and a some other fd.
I added them to the rust library `mio`, but during debugging with strace I found out this is an epoll issue.

When I add stdin to epoll, the epoll_wait returns instantly. It doesn't matter if I have the shell/term connected or pipe something else in (e.g. `cat`).

The minimal C code to observe this:

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    int fd = epoll_create(5);

    struct epoll_event event;

    event.events = EPOLLIN;
    event.data.fd = 0;

    epoll_ctl(fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, &event);

    for (;;) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Going into epoll_wait\n");
        epoll_wait(fd, &event, 1, 0);
        fprintf(stderr, "Going into read: %d\n", event.data.fd);

        printf("%ld\n", read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your return values!  Any of these things could be failing and you'd never know.

Comment: Set `timeout` to `-1` rather than `0`. Come on, it's the first thing to do - to read the manual!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timeout value `0` on `epoll_wait()` means: return immediately and only report currently pending events.

You need to specify timeout value `-1`, which means, "wait indefinitely for events":

```
epoll_wait(fd, &event, 1, -1);
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Right, I was being stupid. So I messed up my minimal test.

Comment: @Ongy Perhaps you mixed it up with `select()`, where a timeout-parameter `0` (being a NULL-pointer there) means "wait indefinitely".

Comment: And I think poll aswell. Yes. Though the actual rust library that I want to use, that brought me into this does properly do -1, that was a mistake I did in my sample code. I wanted to post it as separate question (without referencing the code I butchered), but I have to wait for 90 minutes -.-

Answer (score 1):

[`man epoll_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html):

> Specifying a timeout equal to zero cause `epoll_wait()` to return immediately.